# Отобрать уникальные по коду и суммировать их значения

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных, group-by

Исходный DF:

```
Код                       Название     Сумма
03.2.01.01-0001         Цемент           300
14.5.06.03-0002         Паста            125
03.2.01.01-0001         Цемент           120
14.5.06.03-0002         Паста            62
```

Надо получить:

```
Код                       Название     Сумма
03.2.01.01-0001         Цемент           420
14.5.06.03-0002         Паста            187
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сгруппируйте по столбцам `["Код", "Название"]` и просуммируйте столбец `"Сумма"`:

```
In [106]: df.groupby(["Код", "Название"])["Сумма"].sum().reset_index()
Out[106]:
               Код Название  Сумма
0  03.2.01.01-0001   Цемент    420
1  14.5.06.03-0002    Паста    187
```